# Open DICOM file R can not find directory

Tags: r, dicom

I have just started to use R. 
I am trying to operate with dicom file format. I already installed oro.dicom
but still can not open the file and its header...

From my interactive session:

```
>list.files("P:Desktop/Daten/TCM_extract/R_Files/Data/DICOM")
[1] "Exam 1"          "neck_bradon.dcm"


>neck <- readDICOM (neck_bradom)
Error in list.files(path) : object 'neck_bradom' not found

>neck <- readDICOM (neck_bradon)
Error in list.files(path) : object 'neck_bradon' not found

>neck <- readDICOM (neck_bradon.dcm)
```

Where should `.dcm` files be located? Why doesn't this program did not see it?

Comment: @JohnnyQ Please note the revised formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply missing a slash between "P:" and "Desktop"?

```
>list.files("P:/Desktop/Daten/TCM_extract/R_Files/Data/DICOM")
```